# Data in highchart JSON format is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have code like this

```
 public static string summarydata(string RegNo)
    {

        try
        {
            TrackDataEntities1 sd = new TrackDataEntities1();

            var mdata = new TrackDataEntities1().spsumdata(RegNo)
            .Select(s => new { month = s.Month }).ToArray();

            var sdata = new TrackDataEntities1().spsumdata(RegNo)
             .Select(s => new { s.VName, s.total }).ToArray();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mdata) + "*" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sdata);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }
```

now this return me data like this

```
"[{\"month\":\"July\"},{\"month\":\"June\"},{\"month\":\"June\"},
 {\"month\":\"August\"},{\"month\":\"July\"},{\"month\":\"June\"},
 {\"month\":\"May\"},{\"month\":\"June\"}]*[{\"VName\":\"DDSB\",\"total\":1},
 {\"VName\":\"DPSB\",\"total\":1},{\"VName\":\"DSB\",\"total\":1},
 {\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":5},{\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":11},
 {\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":7},{\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":1},
 {\"VName\":\"PSB\",\"total\":1}]"
```

jquery
**UPDATED JQUERY**
    
            $(function () {

```
            $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var regno = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
                var obj = {};
                obj.RegNo = regno;
                Getsumdata(obj);
                return false;

            });
        });
        function Getsumdata(obj) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/summarydata",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                   alert(JSON.stringify(result.d));

                var data1 = result.d.split('*')[0];
                console.log(typeof (data1)); //Still a String...
                var data11 = JSON.parse(data1);
                console.log(data11); //

                    $('#sum').highcharts({
                        title: {
                            text: 'Combination chart'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: data11,

                            title: {
                                text: null
                            }
                        },
                        labels: {
                            items: [{
                                html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                                style: {
                                    left: '50px',
                                    top: '18px',
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                       // series:data2
                      series: [{
                        type: 'column',
                        name: 'Jane',
                        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
                    }, {
                        type: 'column',
                        name: 'John',
                        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
                    }, {
                        type: 'column',
                        name: 'Joe',
                        data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
                    },
                   ]
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

but chart look like this

[image: chart]

Now the question is JSON look correct i think so why data is not populated in chart .. i use BAR highchart

any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not passing correct data to categories and series's.
Please transform your data in such a way that,
data1 represent categories, should look like this

```
["May","June","July","August"]
```

while  your data2  represent the series data which you want to plot for a given month, should look like below.

```
[1,10,12,5]
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ for sample hight chart....

Answer (score 2):

1. `data2` is still a string, you have to parse it.
2. Take a look at the  [Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.data) on how to add chart data, you have to transform your current data.

```js
var a = "[{\"month\":\"July\"},{\"month\":\"June\"},{\"month\":\"June\"}, {\"month\":\"August\"},{\"month\":\"July\"},{\"month\":\"June\"}, {\"month\":\"May\"},{\"month\":\"June\"}]*[{\"VName\":\"DDSB\",\"total\":1}, {\"VName\":\"DPSB\",\"total\":1},{\"VName\":\"DSB\",\"total\":1}, {\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":5},{\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":11}, {\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":7},{\"VName\":\"MV\",\"total\":1}, {\"VName\":\"PSB\",\"total\":1}]";

var d = a.split('*')[1];
console.log(typeof(d)); //Still a String...
var e = JSON.parse(d);
console.log(e); //Yay an object.
```

Comment: when i try this ..     success: function (result) {
                    var d = result.split('*')[1];
                    console.log(typeof (d)); //Still a String...
                    var e = JSON.parse(d);
                    console.log(e);  and  write e on series like this ..series: e this show error  result.split is not a function